# URL variable matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexof

I'm having a tough time figuring out why this is not working. For some reason the If statement is firing on more than just the item that matches. I am trying to run through each section in my sidebar to see if the name of a section title is contained in / part of the current url so i can tell that section to be active.

I cannot match the exact url, because my structure is setup like this:

```
<div class="row">
  // inside each section (row) div is a section title link, ie: /section-link/
  // and the section navigation links, ie: /section-link/page-link
</div>
<div class="row">
...
</div>
and so on.
```

I need to see if the /section-link/ is part of the current url and if so, set the section that contains that section title/link to be the active section. that way the title and all links within the section will trigger the match and set the section to be active.

All my alerts return the correct data.

```
/* active sidebar section */
        $("#sidebar .row").each(function(){ 
            var currentSection = $(this);
            var sectionTitle = $(this).find("h1 a").text();
            //alert(sectionTitle);

            var sectionTitleSlug = sectionTitle.toLowerCase();
            var sectionTitleSlug = sectionTitleSlug.replace(/[^\w ]+/g,'');
            var sectionTitleSlug = sectionTitleSlug.replace(/ +/g,'-');
            //alert(sectionTitleSlug);

            if(window.location.pathname.indexOf(sectionTitleSlug) > -1) {
                //alert(sectionTitleSlug);
                $(currentSection).addClass("activeSection");
                var activeSectionIndex = $(".activeSection").index();
                $(".accordion").accordion("option", "active", activeSectionIndex);
            };
        });
```

Would appreciate any insight!~

UPDATE:
I have also tried `if(window.location.href.indexOf(sectionTitleSlug) > -1)`

Comment: If you get the third alert for other sections, that means those section's slug are also part of the location path, have you checked the actual value of `window.location.pathname`?

Comment: the links for each are: section1) /bioanalysis/ -- section2) /preclinical-services/ -- section3) /clinical-services/ .... the alert to check the paths shows they shouldnt ALL be matching.

Comment: can you give an example-pair of `sectionTitle` and `location.pathname`

Comment: the 3 sections i have currently have the following titles and links: Bioanalysis (/bioanalysis), Preclinical Services (/preclinical-services), and Clinical Services (/clinical-services). 'sectionTitleSlug' for each matches the url path - for some reason the IF statement is firing on the last two .... is it somehow just matching the "services" part?

Comment: yes- it is matching the "clinical-services" part of "preclinical-services" and "clinical-services" -- how do i add the slashes to make sure it matches like this: /path-link/ instead of just the text?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I think i got it  :)

Revised IF STATEMENT:

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("/"+ sectionTitleSlug +"/") > -1) {
  //
};
```

This way it matches /sectionTitleSlug/ (so it pinpoints a specific directory and not just the text).